# Netbeans PHP autocomplete for PDO?

Tags: php, netbeans, pdo, netbeans-7

Is there a way to set up autocomplete for PDO in Netbeans? version 7.3

Comment: What do you mean with autocomplete? SQL query autocomplete?

Comment: PDO methods, and declaration of objects.

Comment: as far as I know it works out of the box if you have installed the PHP plugin. For me it does (version 7.2.1).

Comment: Type something and then Strg+Space and the autocomplete box apears.. i.e. PD and then Strg+Space.. works fine for me in the actual NetBeans 7.3 RC1 version

Comment: You really need to provide more information in your question. A code example would have made this much easier to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the PHP plug-in installed in Netbeans...

[image]

...then it should automatically be present, but just to be clear: You can't auto-complete the SQL in your statements, only the PDO commands. Like so...

[image]

Is this what you mean?

Comment: @user1681542 Well do you have the PHP plug-in installed?

Comment: Yes. It highlights and autocompletes most of the stuff for php.

Comment: @user1681542 Hmm. Those screenshots were taken from a clean install of Netbeans 7.3 + PHP. Everything works perfectly for me :-/

Comment: is it because I declared my dbh that holds a pdo object as private?

Comment: @user1681542 No, mine is private, too. Maybe you should post an example of your code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The penny dropped in your [comment on Django's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147535/netbeans-php-autocomplete-for-pdo#comment21326722_15147599). You need to provide type hints for your IDE

```
class Foo {
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $dbh;
```